# What solution should I use to generate a list of all possible alphabetic combinaisons?

Tags: algorithm, combinations

I want to generate a list of all the possible combinations of the following characters with a minimum length of 3 characters and a maximum length of 12 characters.

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890_
```

I though of using PHP to do so this but this operation requires too much memory. What would be the best tool to achieve this?

Comment: Do you realize how long the output will be? There are 37 characters, which means 37**12 (37 to the power of 12) possible combinations of 12 characters... There is a total of 6765811783780034854 combinations of 3 to 12 characters.

Comment: Do you know the difference between *combination* and *permutation*? (When the order doesn't matter, it's a combination. When the order *does* matter, it's a permutation.)  Is your question about combinations or about permutations?

Comment: @Stef Yes yes yes

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' What do you call it when the order does matter but we allow repetitions?

Comment: @Stef: [Permutation with repetition](https://www.mathsisfun.com/combinatorics/combinations-permutations.html)

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Terrible choice of words, in my humble opinion. It doesn't correspond to a permutation at all - a permutation is a bijection of a set onto itself. I've never seen the word "permutation" used for what is merely an element of the Cartesian product, apart from the website you just linked; however, I did see the word "combination" used for that purpose in many places; for instance, people talk about the "combination" for a lock or for a Mastermind game, and both of those allow repetition.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you set a limit on each run; For example all possibilities with 5 characters in one run, and all with 7 in another. And write a code to send the output after each run to a text file so you have all the possibilities and
That would take less memory.

example with numbers in python:

```
# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
listx=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
#one letter
for i in listx:
    print(i)
#two letters
for i in listx:
    for j in listx:
        print(f"{i}{j}")
```

and it goes on and on...

output=>
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
10
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
20
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
30
41
42
43
44
45
46
47
48
49
40
51
52
53
54
55
56
57
58
59
50
61
62
63
64
65
66
67
68
69
60
71
72
73
74
75
76
77
78
79
70
81
82
83
84
85
86
87
88
89
80
91
92
93
94
95
96
97
98
99
90
01
02
03
04
05
06
07
08
09
00

Comment: I have a limit: min. 3 characters and max. 12 characters

Answer (score 0):

In python, there is [a function `itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) which returns the combinations you want for a fixed number of characters. You can call it repeatedly to get each number of characters between 3 and 12.

```py
def get_combinations(charset, begin, end):
  result = []
  for i in range(begin, end+1):
    result.extend(''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(charset, repeat=i))
  return result

print(get_combinations('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_', 3, 5))
# ['aaa', 'aab', 'aac', 'aad', 'aae', 'aaf', 'aag', 'aah', 'aai', 'aaj', 'aak', 'aal', 'aam', 'aan', 'aao', 'aap', 'aaq', 'aar', 'aas', 'aat', 'aau', 'aav', 'aaw', 'aax', 'aay', 'aaz', 'aa0', 'aa1', 'aa2', 'aa3', 'aa4', 'aa5', 'aa6', 'aa7', 'aa8', 'aa9', 'aa_', 'aba', 'abb', 'abc', 'abd', 'abe', 'abf', 'abg', 'abh', 'abi', 'abj', 'abk', 'abl', 'abm', 'abn', 'abo', 'abp', 'abq', 'abr', 'abs', 'abt', 'abu', 'abv', 'abw', 'abx', 'aby', 'abz', 'ab0', 'ab1', 'ab2', 'ab3', 'ab4', 'ab5', 'ab6', 'ab7', 'ab8', 'ab9', 'ab_', 'aca', 'acb', 'acc', 'acd', 'ace', 'acf', 'acg', 'ach', 'aci', 'acj', 'ack', 'acl', 'acm', 'acn', 'aco', 'acp', 'acq', 'acr', 'acs', 'act', 'acu', 'acv', 'acw', 'acx', 'acy', 'acz', 'ac0', 'ac1', 'ac2', 'ac3', 'ac4', 'ac5', 'ac6', 'ac7', 'ac8', 'ac9', 'ac_', 'ada', 'adb', 'adc', 'add', 'ade', 'adf', 'adg', 'adh', 'adi', 'adj', 'adk', 'adl', 'adm', 'adn', 'ado', 'adp', 'adq', 'adr', 'ads', 'adt', 'adu', 'adv', 'adw', 'adx', 'ady', 'adz', 'ad0', 'ad1', 'ad2', 'ad3', 'ad4', 'ad5', 'ad6', 'ad7', 'ad8', 'ad9', 'ad_', 'aea', 'aeb', 'aec', 'aed', 'aee', 'aef', 'aeg', ..., '__o0', '__o1', '__o2', '__o3', '__o4', '__o5', '__o6', '__o7', '__o8', '__o9', '__o_', '__pa', '__pb', '__pc', '__pd', '__pe', '__pf', '__pg', '__ph', '__pi', '__pj', '__pk', '__pl', '__pm', '__pn', '__po', '__pp', '__pq', '__pr', '__ps', '__pt', '__pu', '__pv', '__pw', '__px', '__py', '__pz', '__p0', '__p1', '__p2', '__p3', '__p4', '__p5', '__p6', '__p7', '__p8', '__p9', '__p_', '__qa', '__qb', '__qc', '__qd', '__qe', '__qf', '__qg', '__qh', '__qi', '__qj', '__qk', '__ql', '__qm', '__qn', '__qo', '__qp', '__qq', '__qr', '__qs', '__qt', '__qu', '__qv', '__qw', '__qx', '__qy', '__qz', '__q0', '__q1', '__q2', '__q3', '__q4', '__q5', '__q6', '__q7', '__q8', '__q9', '__q_', '__ra', '__rb', '__rc', '__rd', '__re', '__rf', '__rg', '__rh', '__ri', '__rj', '__rk', '__rl', '__rm', '__rn', '__ro', '__rp', '__rq', '__rr', '__rs', '__rt', '__ru', '__rv', '__rw', '__rx', '__ry', '__rz', '__r0', '__r1', '__r2', '__r3', '__r4', '__r5', '__r6', '__r7', '__r8', '__r9', '__r_', '__sa', '__sb', '__sc', '__sd', '__se', '__sf', '__sg', '__sh', '__si', '__sj', '__sk', '__sl', '__sm', '__sn', '__so', '__sp', '__sq', '__sr', '__ss', '__st', '__su', '__sv', '__sw', '__sx', '__sy', '__sz', '__s0', '__s1', '__s2', '__s3', '__s4', '__s5', '__s6', '__s7', '__s8', '__s9', '__s_', '__ta', '__tb', '__tc', '__td', '__te', '__tf', '__tg', '__th', '__ti', '__tj', '__tk', '__tl', '__tm', '__tn', '__to', '__tp', '__tq', '__tr', '__ts', '__tt', '__tu', '__tv', '__tw', '__tx', '__ty', '__tz', '__t0', '__t1', '__t2', '__t3', '__t4', '__t5', '__t6', '__t7', '__t8', '__t9', '__t_', '__ua', '__ub', '__uc', '__ud', '__ue', '__uf', '__ug', '__uh', '__ui', '__uj', '__uk', '__ul', '__um', '__un', '__uo', '__up', '__uq', '__ur', '__us', '__ut', '__uu', '__uv', '__uw', '__ux', '__uy', '__uz', '__u0', '__u1', '__u2', '__u3', '__u4', '__u5', '__u6', '__u7', '__u8', '__u9', '__u_', '__va', '__vb', '__vc', '__vd', '__ve', '__vf', '__vg', '__vh', '__vi', '__vj', '__vk', '__vl', '__vm', '__vn', '__vo', '__vp', '__vq', '__vr', '__vs', '__vt', '__vu', '__vv', '__vw', '__vx', '__vy', '__vz', '__v0', '__v1', '__v2', '__v3', '__v4', '__v5', '__v6', '__v7', '__v8', '__v9', '__v_', '__wa', '__wb', '__wc', '__wd', '__we', '__wf', '__wg', '__wh', '__wi', '__wj', '__wk', '__wl', '__wm', '__wn', '__wo', '__wp', '__wq', '__wr', '__ws', '__wt', '__wu', '__wv', '__ww', '__wx', '__wy', '__wz', '__w0', '__w1', '__w2', '__w3', '__w4', '__w5', '__w6', '__w7', '__w8', '__w9', '__w_', '__xa', '__xb', '__xc', '__xd', '__xe', '__xf', '__xg', '__xh', '__xi', '__xj', '__xk', '__xl', '__xm', '__xn', '__xo', '__xp', '__xq', '__xr', '__xs', '__xt', '__xu', '__xv', '__xw', '__xx', '__xy', '__xz', '__x0', '__x1', '__x2', '__x3', '__x4', '__x5', '__x6', '__x7', '__x8', '__x9', '__x_', '__ya', '__yb', '__yc', '__yd', '__ye', '__yf', '__yg', '__yh', '__yi', '__yj', '__yk', '__yl', '__ym', '__yn', '__yo', '__yp', '__yq', '__yr', '__ys', '__yt', '__yu', '__yv', '__yw', '__yx', '__yy', '__yz', '__y0', '__y1', '__y2', '__y3', '__y4', '__y5', '__y6', '__y7', '__y8', '__y9', '__y_', '__za', '__zb', '__zc', '__zd', '__ze', '__zf', '__zg', '__zh', '__zi', '__zj', '__zk', '__zl', '__zm', '__zn', '__zo', '__zp', '__zq', '__zr', '__zs', '__zt', '__zu', '__zv', '__zw', '__zx', '__zy', '__zz', '__z0', '__z1', '__z2', '__z3', '__z4', '__z5', '__z6', '__z7', '__z8', '__z9', '__z_', '__0a', '__0b', '__0c', '__0d', '__0e', '__0f', '__0g', '__0h', '__0i', '__0j', '__0k', '__0l', '__0m', '__0n', '__0o', '__0p', '__0q', '__0r', '__0s', '__0t', '__0u', '__0v', '__0w', '__0x', '__0y', '__0z', '__00', '__01', '__02', '__03', '__04', '__05', '__06', '__07', '__08', '__09', '__0_', '__1a', '__1b', '__1c', '__1d', '__1e', '__1f', '__1g', '__1h', '__1i', '__1j', '__1k', '__1l', '__1m', '__1n', '__1o', '__1p', '__1q', '__1r', '__1s', '__1t', '__1u', '__1v', '__1w', '__1x', '__1y', '__1z', '__10', '__11', '__12', '__13', '__14', '__15', '__16', '__17', '__18', '__19', '__1_', '__2a', '__2b', '__2c', '__2d', '__2e', '__2f', '__2g', '__2h', '__2i', '__2j', '__2k', '__2l', '__2m', '__2n', '__2o', '__2p', '__2q', '__2r', '__2s', '__2t', '__2u', '__2v', '__2w', '__2x', '__2y', '__2z', '__20', '__21', '__22', '__23', '__24', '__25', '__26', '__27', '__28', '__29', '__2_', '__3a', '__3b', '__3c', '__3d', '__3e', '__3f', '__3g', '__3h', '__3i', '__3j', '__3k', '__3l', '__3m', '__3n', '__3o', '__3p', '__3q', '__3r', '__3s', '__3t', '__3u', '__3v', '__3w', '__3x', '__3y', '__3z', '__30', '__31', '__32', '__33', '__34', '__35', '__36', '__37', '__38', '__39', '__3_', '__4a', '__4b', '__4c', '__4d', '__4e', '__4f', '__4g', '__4h', '__4i', '__4j', '__4k', '__4l', '__4m', '__4n', '__4o', '__4p', '__4q', '__4r', '__4s', '__4t', '__4u', '__4v', '__4w', '__4x', '__4y', '__4z', '__40', '__41', '__42', '__43', '__44', '__45', '__46', '__47', '__48', '__49', '__4_', '__5a', '__5b', '__5c', '__5d', '__5e', '__5f', '__5g', '__5h', '__5i', '__5j', '__5k', '__5l', '__5m', '__5n', '__5o', '__5p', '__5q', '__5r', '__5s', '__5t', '__5u', '__5v', '__5w', '__5x', '__5y', '__5z', '__50', '__51', '__52', '__53', '__54', '__55', '__56', '__57', '__58', '__59', '__5_', '__6a', '__6b', '__6c', '__6d', '__6e', '__6f', '__6g', '__6h', '__6i', '__6j', '__6k', '__6l', '__6m', '__6n', '__6o', '__6p', '__6q', '__6r', '__6s', '__6t', '__6u', '__6v', '__6w', '__6x', '__6y', '__6z', '__60', '__61', '__62', '__63', '__64', '__65', '__66', '__67', '__68', '__69', '__6_', '__7a', '__7b', '__7c', '__7d', '__7e', '__7f', '__7g', '__7h', '__7i', '__7j', '__7k', '__7l', '__7m', '__7n', '__7o', '__7p', '__7q', '__7r', '__7s', '__7t', '__7u', '__7v', '__7w', '__7x', '__7y', '__7z', '__70', '__71', '__72', '__73', '__74', '__75', '__76', '__77', '__78', '__79', '__7_', '__8a', '__8b', '__8c', '__8d', '__8e', '__8f', '__8g', '__8h', '__8i', '__8j', '__8k', '__8l', '__8m', '__8n', '__8o', '__8p', '__8q', '__8r', '__8s', '__8t', '__8u', '__8v', '__8w', '__8x', '__8y', '__8z', '__80', '__81', '__82', '__83', '__84', '__85', '__86', '__87', '__88', '__89', '__8_', '__9a', '__9b', '__9c', '__9d', '__9e', '__9f', '__9g', '__9h', '__9i', '__9j', '__9k', '__9l', '__9m', '__9n', '__9o', '__9p', '__9q', '__9r', '__9s', '__9t', '__9u', '__9v', '__9w', '__9x', '__9y', '__9z', '__90', '__91', '__92', '__93', '__94', '__95', '__96', '__97', '__98', '__99', '__9_', '___a', '___b', '___c', '___d', '___e', '___f', '___g', '___h', '___i', '___j', '___k', '___l', '___m', '___n', '___o', '___p', '___q', '___r', '___s', '___t', '___u', '___v', '___w', '___x', '___y', '___z', '___0', '___1', '___2', '___3', '___4', '___5', '___6', '___7', '___8', '___9', '____']
```

Note how I called the function with parameters 3 and 5 instead of 3 and 12. With parameters 3 and 5, the number of combinations is already 71268771. Over 71 millions. With parameters 3 and 12, the number of combinations would be 6765811783780034854. That's 6.8 * 10**18. This is nearly one thousand million times the number of humans on Earth.

Comment: I love this. How did you get the number 6765811783780034854 by the way?

Comment: @miniLustucru In python: `sum(37**i for i in range(3,13))`. Note that it's only slightly larger than `37**12`, since `37**12` is much larger than the 9 other terms in this sum.